# $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-t} ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 t x}}) \, dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\log (\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2\sqrt{1-4x}})$

Tags: integration

How to prove

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-t} \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 t
   x}}\bigg) \, dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\log \bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2\sqrt{1-4x}}\bigg)$$

Comment: Please share ur efforts

Comment: are you sure that this result is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird one. Put $t = \frac{1}{4x}(1-u^2)$. The limits become $1$ and $\sqrt{1-4x}$. Then
$$ \frac{dt}{1-t} = \frac{2u \, du}{1-4x-u^2}, $$
while $1/\sqrt{1-4tx} = 1/u$.  But $1-4x-u^2 = (\sqrt{1-4x}+u)(\sqrt{1-4x}-u)$, so we can cancel part of this with the numerator of
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1/u = \frac{u-\sqrt{1-4x}}{u\sqrt{1-4x}},$$
and we end up with the easily integrable
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\int_{\sqrt{1-4x}}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-4x}+u}, $$
which gives
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}} \left( \log{\left(1+\sqrt{1-4x}\right)} - \log{\left(2\sqrt{1-4x}\right)} \right) $$
as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

$$\sqrt{1-4xt}-\sqrt{1-4x}={4x(1-t)\over\sqrt{1-4xt}+\sqrt{1-4x}}$$

which suggests the change of variable $u=4xt$.

Hint 2:  Letting $1-u=w^2$ (and abbreviating $\sqrt{1-4x}$ to $a$), we have

$$\int{du\over a\sqrt{1-u}(\sqrt{1-u}+a)}={1\over a}\int{-2wdw\over w(w+a)}$$

Now use partial fractions.